# Polynomial rings and congruence classes

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's consider the polynomial $m(x)$ over a field $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$.
We know that $[m(x)]_{m(x)}=m(a)=0$.

Now $m(x)=x^{3}+1$; in my lectures slide, it's said at this point that:

$m(a)=0$ implies that $a^{3}=2$.

What this means ?

Moreover, in the slides about the modulo arithmetic with polynomials it's said that, when we work with polynomial whose coefficients are modulo n then the negative coefficients equals to the positive ones. But why ?

Comment: What does $[m(x)]_{m(x)}$ represent, in your notation?

Comment: $m(a)=0$ means that $a^3+1 = 0$, which means that $a^3=-1$. However, in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $-1=2$ (since $-1\equiv 2\pmod{3}$), so $a^3=-1$ is the same thing as $a^3=2$.

Comment: Your last question is unclear; you should quote exactly what it says, because your paraphrase does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Wait, we are working in modulo m(x).... not modulo 3....

Comment: You are working over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so every constant you see is actually an integer modulo $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working in modulo 3, so if $m(a) = 0$, we have $a^3 \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. So this means $a^3 = 2$.

Comment: Wait, we are working in modulo m(x).... not modulo 3....

Comment: @AleQuercia Yes, but m(x) is defined over the field $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so we can still use such equivalences.

Comment: I would like to study this in a book, which are correct the keywords for these arguments ? So i can search on a volume

Comment: @AleQuercia I'm not quite sure what keywords would be used for these arguments to search. If you want justification, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a subfield of the field $\mathbb{Z_3}[x]/m(x)$.

Comment: Does this mean that we can work modulo m(x) and modulo 3 simultaneously ? :S

Comment: @AleQuercia Yes, modulo 3 is part of working in modulo m(x) since m(x) is already taken modulo 3.

Comment: Thanks so much, i've understood everything except one thing. Why can we just simplify modulo 3 the coefficients of the polynomials, what assures us that we don't mess up things doing so ?

Comment: The coefficients are *elements* of $\mathbb{Z}_3$. They are equivalence classes modulo $3$. You aren't "simlifying modulo $3$ the coefficients". The coefficients *are* taken modulo 3.